# Switch statement calling a void class

Tags: java

```
public static void sendMessage(String sender){
    Scanner scTwo = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your recipient: ");
    String recipient = scTwo.next();
    System.out.println("Enter your message: ");
    String message = scTwo.next();

    Message myMessage = new Message(sender, message);


}

public static void readMessage(Mailbox myMail){
    for (int x = 0; x < myMail.getMail().size(); x++){
        System.out.println("Email Number: " + x + " from " + myMail.getMail().get(x).getSender());
        System.out.println("Message: " + myMail.getMail().get(x).getText()); 
    }
}       


public static void readUserName(String userName){
        ArrayList<Mailbox> users = new ArrayList<Mailbox>();
        for(int x = 0; x < users.size(); x++){
            if (userName.equals(users.get(x))){
                System.out.println("Hello " + userName + ".");
            } else {
                users.add(new Mailbox(userName));
                System.out.println("Hello " + userName + ", welcome.");
            }
        }   
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean emailOn = true;
    boolean done = false;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (emailOn){
                while(!done){       
                    System.out.println("Enter username (-1 to quit): ");

                    if (sc.hasNextInt()){
                        String userName = sc.next();
                        readUserName(userName);

                        System.out.println("Your Options ");    
                        System.out.println("(1) Read your email");
                        System.out.println("(2) Send an email");
                        System.out.println("(3) Log out of Email");
                        int number = sc.nextInt();

                        switch(number){     
                        case 1 : readMessage(userName); break;
                        case 2 : sendMessage(userName); break;
                        case 3 : done = true; break;
                        }
                        //sc.next() = new Mailbox();
                    }       
                }
                System.out.println("Logged out, have a nice day now!");
                System.out.println("Enter \"-1\" to turn off.");

                if(sc.nextInt() == -1){
                    emailOn = false;
                } else {
                    emailOn = false;
                }

            }// ArrayList<Mailbox> mailboxes
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
}


class Mailbox{
private ArrayList<Message> mail;
private String userNameTaken;

public Mailbox(String aUserName){
    userNameTaken = aUserName;
}

public String getUserName(){
    return userNameTaken;
}

public void addMessage(Message aMessage){
            mail.add(aMessage);
}

public ArrayList<Message> getMail(){
    return mail;

}



class Message{
private String sender;
private String text;

public Message(String aSender, String messageBody){
    sender = aSender;
    text = messageBody;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}
public String getSender(){
    return sender;
}
```

In case 1 I am trying to call readMessage however since it is void it won't work.  I'm not exactly sure how to get around this.  Do I new to call up the ArrayList first for the users and then call the messages to print them?  I do innitilize myMail in readUserName.  However I can't convert a string to a mailbox so readMessage(username) isn't applicable.

Comment: There is no such thing as calling a class, or a void class.

Comment: @DaveNewton Case 1 will not.  I am trying to make it use readMessage

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @DaveNewton  a string can't be converted to a Mailbox.  That's another part that's confusing to me.  I created a mailbox with the username but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Pass in the mailbox you created? I'd consider taking a big step back; just throwing code around will be pretty inefficient in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Call your method with one argument parameter as,

```
case 1 : readMessage(myMail); break;
```

Note: Before that you should declare and innitialize `myMail` as what younwant